# how to make jquery sortable work on dynamically fetched data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable to sort elements. This works fine until statically used. Once the data updates dynamically (via AJAX), it simply stops working. Is there a way I can make sortable work on dynamically fetched data.

The below method works when used statically only.

```
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    // SORT CODES HERE
  }).disableSelection();
```

To make it work on dynamically updated elements, I tried to add `refresh` found in the documentation [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) but this doesn't seem to work as well.

```
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    // SORT CODES HERE
  }).disableSelection().sortable("refresh");
```

Any idea how to fix this for dynamic elements?

Comment: What does your update code look like? The sortable widget is applied to a parent element and then it's child elements are sortable. As long as you don't modify the parent element after calling `.sortable()` on it, you should be able to mutate the child elements however you want without needing to refresh.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode never mind :) I tried a different approach to solve it. I called the sortable function on every AJAX call to make it work. It's working as expected. I knew I could do this but I was looking for a standalone method that would allow me to achieve the same result without calling the sortable function on every call. But no worries. Unless it drops performance at a certain point of time (if ever, in future), this approach I took is okay too.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but you shouldn't have to. I made a quick fiddle to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/pnaLhge9/. Notice how `.sortable()` is only called once. Although you can click the button and dynamically add as many children as you want, and they're all sortable, without doing anything with the sortable widget that's already initialized. If your code is breaking sortability, I have a suspicion that you are somehow modifying the parent, and thus breaking the sortable widget.